# accessing list in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I'm storing key and value in a dictionary called campaign_name, then access the value using randvalue. That works fine. But when I try to access certain element in the randvalue, let's say randvalue[0] or randvalue[1] it would throw an error.

I can print(randvalue) perfectly and the value would show like this [[16949.070963, 2694507, 76606]]. But I can't print just 16949.070963. My complete section of code is as follows: Thanks for the help.

```
  def startchecking():
        storepast()
        # loading file into opepyxl
        ref_workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(path)
        # Grab all the sheet name in the workbook
        workbook_tab = ref_workbook.get_sheet_names()
        for i in workbook_tab:
            ws = ref_workbook[i]
            randvalue=campaign_name.get(str(ws['B4'].value))
            print(randvalue)
            temptext = "Starting Check" + str(ws)
            textoutput(temptext)
        checkdaily(45, 52)
```

Comment: Can you supply a [mcve]?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your `randvalue` is a list of list, try using `randvalue[0][0]` to get 16949.070963.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that randvalue is a list in list. So try to print

`print(randvalue[0][0])`

so it will print 16949.070963